# Invisibility of constants and extention functions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, visibility

I am merely learning Kotlin Koans, so my question can be very stupid.

Solving the Operators Overloading chapter I got two files, both on the root level:

The first one is red-marked by errors - I put them as comments

```
import TimeInterval       // is gray
import addTimeIntervals   // is gray

data class MyDate(val year: Int, val month: Int, val dayOfMonth: Int)


operator fun MyDate.plus(timeInterval: TimeInterval): MyDate
        = MyDate.addTimeIntervals(Period(timeInterval, 1))   // Unresolved reference: addTimeIntervals
operator fun MyDate.plus(period: Period): MyDate
        = MyDate.addTimeIntervals(period)      //Unresolved reference: addTimeIntervals

fun task1(today: MyDate): MyDate {
    return today + YEAR + WEEK  // Unresolved reference: YEAR //Unresolved reference: WEEK
}
```

The second one is without errors:

```
import java.util.Calendar

/*
 * Returns the date after the given time interval.
 * The interval is specified as the given amount of days, weeks of years.
 * Usages:
 * 'date.addTimeIntervals(TimeInterval.DAY, 4)'
 * 'date.addTimeIntervals(TimeInterval.WEEK, 3)'
 */
fun MyDate.addTimeIntervals(period: Period): MyDate {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.set(year + if (period.timeInterval == TimeInterval.YEAR) period.amount else 0, month, dayOfMonth)
    var timeInMillis = c.timeInMillis
    val millisecondsInADay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L
    timeInMillis += period.amount * when (period.timeInterval) {
        TimeInterval.DAY -> millisecondsInADay
        TimeInterval.WEEK -> 7 * millisecondsInADay
        TimeInterval.YEAR -> 0L
    }
    val result = Calendar.getInstance()
    result.timeInMillis = timeInMillis
    return MyDate(result.get(Calendar.YEAR), result.get(Calendar.MONTH), result.get(Calendar.DATE))
}

// Supported intervals that might be added to dates:
enum class TimeInterval { DAY, WEEK, YEAR}

operator fun TimeInterval.times(amount: Int): Period = Period(this, amount)

operator fun Int.times(timeInterval: TimeInterval): Period =  timeInterval * this

data class Period(val timeInterval: TimeInterval, val amount: Int)
```

I don't understand why the first file cannot use constants and extension function from the second one. The move of the enum class into the first file does not change anything. The use of constants with classname does help, but the whole theme is about making the code concise, so, it is obviously a wrong solution for that case.

Why are they invisible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it!

The visibility of constant is reached by

```
import EnumName.*
```

The visibility of extension functions is blocked by excessive use of classname as prefix inside other extension functions definitions.